# Combine a point dataset with multi-polygon dataset

Tags: point, merge, combine, geometries

Using QGIS, I need to combine a point dataset with an associated multi-polygon dataset, and clip away any of the polygons which do not have an associated point, please see image attached. The point layer is tree locations and the multi-polygon layer is tree canopy areas, so I need to combine the two to get tree and canopy locations to align, and clip away any of the polygons which do not have an associated point. The two different geometries of the datasets have been tripping me up.

I've tried "Join attributes by location" but I am now receiving a message saying "feature (4160) has invalid geometry...". Can someone please offer a suggestion for overcoming the invalid geometry issue?

[image]

Comment: Which software are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using QGIS

Comment: You can't merge them but you can select by location/join attributes by location then export polys that have points to a new layer.